# Unity 2D get the collision event without the physics

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, physics, collision

I'm using a collider 2D on a box and set it to trigger so my player can walk through it, when when i set it to trigger it doesn't fire the OnCollisionEnter2D anymore, is there a way to keep using the collision event without the physics engine taking in into consideration, if not then is there there another way to achieve this ? (i'm currently checking each frame in the update method and calculating the distance but this seems too heavy)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65293614/1092820) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another function called [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) which may be what you are looking for. This should fire on collision, without causing physical interactions.

You could have OnCollisionEnter2D and OnTriggerEnter2D both call a separate function to handle collisions, if this MonoBehaviour is added to both triggers and non-triggers.